# Why does the spring KafkaConsumer suspend all consumption from n topics when one fails to authorize

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using the spring-kafka 2.3.6.RELEASE library to consume from a number of kafka topics. I'm using a single listener to consume all topics, as the interface allows. I've noted that, if a single topic fails to authorize, the KafkaConsumer instance suspends its thread, ceasing consumption from all topics until the retry interval elapses.

This seems very brittle to me, particularly for a technology focused on resiliency and parallelism.

Has anyone else observed this behaviour, and if so, is there any way to mitigate it beyond writing our own consumer implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring simply delegates to the underlying kafka-clients jar so such things are out of its control.

You can use a separate listener for each topic. For example `@KafkaListener` is a repeatable annotation so you can add multiple annotations to a single method.

Comment: The listener thread is suspended explicitly on line ListenerConsumer#ListenerConsumer:949. The Fetcher instance that the KafkaConsumer delegates to seems to have some resiliency built into it at lines 599 and 626. Here it determines whether other completed fetches (ie. from other topics or partitions) yielded records, and if so does not propagate the TopicAuthException before returning the records.

If the Spring listener didn't suspend, I would imagine the KafkaConsumer from the clients library would continue to successfully fetch records from the authorized topics.

Comment: Re. separate listeners, I considered this but have concerns around scalability as we add more topics.

Comment: I am not sure what you think we can do. The poll must be throwing an exception; otherwise we wouldn't get to line 949.

Comment: It might be useful to toggle whether the consumer sleeps or not on topic authorization exceptions. If we toggled this off, the consumer will continue to poll, and receive messages from the healthy topics, along with occasional exceptions from the unauthorized topic.

Comment: You can set the sleep to zero to do that - use `containerProps.setAuthorizationExceptionRetryInterval(Duration.ZERO)`.